# Ensuring authenticity in Xbee Series 1

Tags: xbee, arduino-uno

I have been working with Xbee for few days and intending to use Xbee (Series 1) +Arduino UNO as part of Wireless Sensor Network. I want the network to be secured, I can use the Xbee's AES capability to make the data transfer secure. But I want to make sure that the sender/receiver all are authentic. How can I be able to ensure that? I want to use AT mode.

What I am trying to say is, suppose there are few nodes (Xbee+Arduino) which collects data by sensor and there is one receiver. The receiver sends command to one of the sensor node (one to one communication) to collect sensor value from that node. My question is, how can that sensor node will be able to know that, the commander is authentic, not some adversary [that somehow knows the command format and sending the command pretending itself as commander]? Is there anyway to configure the Xbee so that it can respond to only authentic commander? There will be only one commander in the network, but is there anyway to set sensor xbee [as we can configure destination address] so that it will only respond to the authentic commander?

Answer (score 0):

In API mode, the Xbee send his address in the trame but in AT mode, the only thing you can do is to check the different node on the net with an ATND. The SL address of the Xbee is unique and than you can say if there is unknown node on your network.

If you see unknown node (keep an array with your node), send an confirmation to the commander and make the commander reply "yes, it was me" or "no, it wasn't me". Be sure to keep the SL (get with ATSL) address of you commander in every node :p

So good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

With a shared AES key, only authentic nodes (devices with the key) can join and send data on the network.  Membership in the network is enough to ensure authenticity/security.  You just have to make sure you keep the AES key secure.

There's a limit to the security in your setup, of course.  If I have physical access to it, I can monitor the serial connection between the Arduino and XBee module to reverse engineer your protocol, then remove the Arduino and replace it with my own host device.  I'll be using your XBee radio module which is already a member of the network, and possibly trusted due to its MAC address.